# UIWebView crashing

Tags: objective-c, ipad, crash

I have a problem with using UIWebViews in an objective-C app we're developing. It crashes any Retina iPad.  Both iPad 1 and 2 behave fine.

The web view is loaded from local HTML/CSS/JS and is dynamic content that contains pricing information so needs to be essentially a mirror of a website which is pre-downloaded to the device.

The page contains lots of images so I think this is memory related.  I've tried reducing the payload on the page which stops the crashes. Obviously the stupidity of Apple to choose to quadruple resolution whilst only doubling memory is a root cause of why it works fine on non-retina devices, but how can I manage memory within the page to prevent iOS from destroying the entire app?

Does iOS automatically store imagery as 2048x1536x32bpp as a bitmap (theoretically 12MB per image?) irrespective of the file format? I've tried converting to JPG / PNG but with no effect on the crashes.  Only reducing the volume of images present on the page stops the crashes.  It's my first foray into iOS development, so please be gentle!

Comment: Do you have any information as to where it crashes? Either from the crash log on the device or from running it with the debugger attached?

Comment: If you think it's the pictures don't load them and give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

iOS won't change the resolution of the original images that the page loads, but of course it will de-serialize them from .png/.jpg to a bitmap in memory for display, so you should start by trying to reduce the resolution of the .png/.jpg images that the page loads.